# finding a nil value in session when accessing value in view

Tags: firebase, swiftui

So i have a sessionStore:

```
class SessionStore: ObservableObject {

var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

@Published var isLoggedIn = false
@Published var userInSession: User?

func listenAuthenticationState() {
    handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({(auth, user) in
        if let user = user {
            let firestoreGetUser = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(user.uid)
            firestoreGetUser.getDocument{(document, error) in
                if let dict = document?.data() {
                    guard let decodedUser = try? User.init(fromDictionary: dict) else { return }
                    self.userInSession = decodedUser
                    print("decoded user = \(decodedUser)")
                }
            }
            self.isLoggedIn = true
            print("user logged in")
        } else {
            self.isLoggedIn = false
            self.userInSession = nil
            print("no one logged in")
        }
    })
}

func logout() {
    do {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
    } catch {

    }
}

func unbind() {
    if let handle = handle {
        Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(handle)
    }
}

deinit {
    unbind()
}
}
```

Its working as expected, I am able to sign in etc.

I have the following to pull the current user data:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore

class ProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {

var uid: String = ""
var email: String = ""
var username: String = ""
var profileURL: String = ""
var bio: String = ""
var occupation: String = ""
var city: String = ""

func LoadAUser(userId: String) {
    Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(userId).getDocument{(snapshot, error) in
        guard let snap = snapshot else {
            print("error fetching data")
            return
        }
        let dict = snap.data()
        guard let decodedUser = try? User.init(fromDictionary: dict!) else { return }
        print("decoded user - load user - \(decodedUser)")
    }
}
}
```

In my view im trying to call it like:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProfileView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
@ObservedObject var profileViewModel = ProfileViewModel()

func loadUserData() {
    profileViewModel.LoadAUser(userId: session.userInSession!.uid)
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Edit Profile")
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
            .font(.system(.title, design: .rounded))
            .foregroundColor(Color("startColor"))
        Spacer()
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("view")
        }.padding()
        .onAppear(perform: loadUserData)
}
}

struct ProfileView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProfileView()
    }
}
```

Im using `.onAppear(perform: loadUserData)` which is causing an issue - `Thread1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping`

I also tried:

```
init() {
    profileViewModel.LoadAUser(userId: session.userInSession!.uid)
}
```

But this also causes the same error.

The thing is I should only be able to get to this view if I'm logged in as this already works:

```
struct InitialView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore

func listen() {
    session.listenAuthenticationState()
}

var body: some View {
    Group {
        if session.isLoggedIn {
            MainView()
        } else {
            NavigationView {
                SignUpView()
            }
        }
    }.onAppear(perform: listen)
}
}
```

I have an initialView()

```
struct InitialView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore

    func listen() {
        session.listenAuthenticationState()
    }

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if session.isLoggedIn {
                MainView()
            } else {
                NavigationView {
                    SignUpView()
                }
            }
        }.onAppear(perform: listen)
    }
}
```

which takes you to the MainView() which has tabs to control which screen you can navigate to, then from here i can go to ProfileView()

Comment: If you see in log `"decoded user = \(decodedUser)"` then show where/how you go to `ProfileView` in code.

Comment: @Asperi those logs don't appear as the app crashes before loading, but i have updated my code to show how i get to ProfileView()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So whats worked for me is passing in Auth instead of session data:

```
func loadUserData() {
    profileViewModel.LoadAUser(userId: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyway by the logic of provided code it is more correct to activate `isLoggedIn` in

```
        let firestoreGetUser = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(user.uid)
        firestoreGetUser.getDocument{(document, error) in
            if let dict = document?.data() {
                guard let decodedUser = try? User.init(fromDictionary: dict) else { return }
                self.userInSession = decodedUser
                print("decoded user = \(decodedUser)")

                self.isLoggedIn = true   // << here !!
                print("user logged in")
            }
        }
```